# Laravel S3 random mime type

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

This is very weird, i'm trying to retrieve an image from AWS S3 form Laravel controller but i get a random Mime type on every reload.

Code in controller

```
public function show($attachment){
    $attachmentTest = Storage::disk('s3')->get("attachments/".$attachment);
    return File::mimeType($attachmentTest);
}
```

And the router:

```
Route::get('attachments/{slug}', [
    'as'         => 'images.show',
    'uses'       => 'AttachmentController@show'
]);
```

Screen capture browser reloading test: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR4HT.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work, you need to get the mimeType directly from the S3. Downloading it get's you the raw image only.

```
public function show($attachment){
  return Storage::disk('s3')->mimeType("attachments/".$attachment);
}
```

Comment: @David select this answer to correct, so the issue can be closed.

Comment: Ok selected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The File facade is for your local filesystem, not S3.  Storage::disk('s3') and File are not compatible with each other.

File::mimeType checks a local file, by filename, for its mime type.  If you pass file contents, instead of a local path, the results may be unpredictable as you are seeing.

Use this reference to see API information for Facades and what method you are actually calling: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades#facade-class-reference